# error while trying to use Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

After installing Angular Material , whenever I import anything form @angular/material I get this error

> error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

I tried deleting node_modules and redownloading using npm install .
tried to reinstall Angular Material ,still I get the same error over and over

Comment: May be related to Ivy. Try this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35399#issuecomment-586662889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot implement angular material using '@angular/material' imports

You have to import the required module that you are going to use in the project like if using Material button then import the using `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';` and then add it in imports array like `MatButtonModule`

```js
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,
  imports: [
      MatButtonModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This would work